# Windows 10 - search not working

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

Windows 10 Pro x64...

I have two users in ,y compnay with the same problem.

If they click the search icon in the bottom (task bar), the nothing happens - no window popping up.

If the click the Startmenu (windows flag) then theres a second deleay before the window shows.

With the Startmenu-window open, if they try to type anything, nothing happens.

All pc has latest Windows Update.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well now I've been strugling with this for so much time and just as I post here, I find a solution.

So for others with same problem...

I logged in as local admin and granted the domain user admin rights on the Pc. Then I logged out and in as the user .... now everything worked fine.

I removed the admin rights for the user again and it still works.

Great! :)